# Autotrader API Integration

Tags: rest-api, api, json

I am looking to pull in a feed of used cars from Autotrader.

Has anyone had **any** luck with the Autotrader API [Docs](https://developers.autotrader.co.uk/api#search-api) and integrating with WordPress? Their current API documentation is very vague - is there any plugin options out there I have not managed to find?

The current REST API exposes adverts and retailers in JSON format which is great - but not sure if anyone had any experience on the best way to go about integration.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. This is kind of out-of-scope for this site, IMO. It would probably be better on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I am looking to do the same. Did you ever get anywhere with this? Thanks

Comment: If it's just making the API work you probably want to ask their developer support. Or did you need help with the WordPress side of things too?

Comment: There are plugins you can use to connect easily to API's https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgetapi/ is one example